# Have two buttons on the same line

Tags: html, button, skype

I would like to have both the "email me" button on the same line as the "skype" button. I am new to HTML so go easy on me.

The code is

```
<!-- emailme Button BEGIN -->
<div id="emailme_div1"></div>
<script>var emailme_id=4714;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.emailmebutton.com/emailme.js"></script>
<!-- emailme Button END -->
<!--Skype 'Skype Me™!' button Begin-->
<a href="skype:grapplerulrich?call"><img src="http://mystatus.skype.com/bigclassic/grapplerulrich" style="border: none;" width="182" height="44" alt="My status" /></a>
<!--Skype 'Skype Me™!' button End-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `float` each button.

Give them a set `width` to space them apart properly.

Add some `margin-top` to the first button to line them up vertically.

```
#emailme_div1{float:left; width:150px; margin-top:9px;}
#skype{float:left;width:150px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/mn8EZ/

Note: this requires adding an `id` to the skype `a href`.

BTW: you will need to clear the `floats` for any content underneath.

Comment: Thanks @grappler.  if this answers the question, you can click the checkmark beside it to let others know it has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

You have to position them relative and use "float:left" to get them next to eachother.
The best way is to put both buttons inside a "container" and then asign both buttons `position:relative` and `float:left`

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/cLEFW/

I've wrapped a div around youre skype script, and added the `position:relative` and the `float:left`. In fact, you dont even need to use `position:relative`, but well... I've done it anyway xD

Comment: Thank you  for your answer but i liked Jason's a bit better because his looked nice together.